# Which is the right measure of dispersion to be used as a proxy for risk for a fat tail distribution?

Tags: finance, kurtosis, heavy-tailed, dispersion

Which is the right measure of dispersion to be used as a proxy for risk for a fat tail distribution ?  Standard Deviation, Mean deviation, Value at risk, what else?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a 'right' measure. However, there are several desirable properties that define a [coherent risk measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure) which are monotonicity, sub-additivity, homogeneity, and translational invariance. Conditional Value at Risk is probably the most popular in the field of engineering (also called Expected shortfall).